# PHP countdown timer problem using javascript

Tags: php, javascript, timer, settimeout, countdown

I'm using php 5.3.6 and mysql 5.1.54 with apache webserver windows edition on my local pc.

And my web host have php 4.0.2 and mysql 4.1.2 with apache webserver linux edition.
I'm using a script and it has a countdown timer using php/javascript.
It does not have any problem in my pc.

But when i upload to my web host and run the code , it shows me '`Nan Nan`' (Not a Number) in countdown field.
Interesting point is: when i change `setTimout(...,1000)` to `setTimeout(...,2000)`, everything will be ok!

But in this case, it countdowns every 2 seconds!, that's not my favorite.
I'm not sure if it is a bug in php version at my web service or it is something else.

Comment: Sounds like a bug in your code. Care to paste relevant lines here?

Comment: Please see http://tinyurl.com/so-hints to learn how to write a good question. You say "it shows" - but you need to tell us *what* shows that!

Comment: window.onload=function(){
  setTimeout(function(){refresh_countdown('time_left', <?=$item_details['id'];?>)}, 1000);

Comment: Paste the JavaScript that line generates as well.

Comment: As a side note, your web host uses PHP 4.0.2 and MySQL 4.1.2?? It is definitely time for an upgrade.

Comment: @George Cummins: most web hosts don't care, as long as they receive their money.

Comment: @WTP: That may be true, but this is not just a money issue. Using 11-year old technology on today's web is a security risk and a maintenance disaster. The host may not care, but the client should.

Comment: There's a bug in the code you pasted.  You're missing a trailing `}` right before the final `;`.

Comment: I try to copy/paste the code...but the editor does not allow me to do it ... :)

Comment: Wow, too many people trying to edit this question! I think I got the full version of the code up there, correctly formatted.

Answer (score 0):

Huh, the code in the question is javascript, i.e. client-side. Why should anything change when this code is on a different host?

Within the javascript you have this php echo statement

```
<?=$item_details['auction_id'];?>
```

On the client-side this should not work so I have to assume you are creating this javascript on the fly server-side and embed it in html somewhere. Hence, the real question is: What array is `$item_details` and where is the data coming from? Take a look at that piece in your php script and if you cannot find the answer yourself edit/update your question with that code.

Comment: It was Solved!...i was using a proxy for connecting to the server. when i remove the proxy connection everything was corrected. Thanks to Adrian and everybody